# Get Text is not working for Data selection from calendar

Tags: robotframework

I used get text/get value with the xpath element, but it's not getting the text/value.

Below are the Code and tried to get text/value and getting element not visible error.

Note : Same element is working For click element.

```
    <div class="cal-month-day  cal-day-inmonth cal-day-future cal-day-has-events" ng-class="{
  'cal-day-outmonth': !day.inMonth,
  'cal-day-inmonth': day.inMonth,
  'cal-day-weekend': day.isWeekend,
  'cal-day-past': day.isPast,
  'cal-day-future': day.isFuture,
  'cal-day-has-events': day.events.length > 0,
  'cal-day-selected': vm.calendarCtrl.isSelectedDate(day),
  'cal-day-open': dayIndex === vm.openDayIndex
  }" ng-click="vm.calendarCtrl.onDateSelection(day.date)">
  <small class="cal-events-num badge badge-important pull-left ng-binding" ng-show="day.badgeTotal > 0 && (vm.calendarConfig.displayAllMonthEvents || day.inMonth)" ng-bind="day.badgeTotal">2</small>
  <span class="pull-right ng-binding" ng-bind="day.label">2</span>
```

Comment: Can you provide the robot script and the actual result? Presently you're leaving us guessing.

Comment: I used Get Text/Get Value xpath=//div[5]/ng-include/div/ng-include/div, but click is working for the same element.
Error Response : Element locator 'xpath=//div[5]/ng-include/div/ng-include/div' did not match any elements.

Comment: Can you update the existing question using the [edit] functionality?

Comment: updated the existing question.